# How can I get dynamically updating Flatlist in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a Ble device, I used react-native-ble-manager, useState, and useEffect to get notifications from event listeners and try to show them on App. I have posted a part of the code related to incoming data.

```
const [dataTest, setDataTest] = useState([]);
const handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = (data) => {
  setDataTest(data.value); // data.value is a object incoming every one second from device.
};

useEffect(() => {
  bleManagerEmitter.addListener("BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic", handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic);
}, []);

const renderData = (item) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

return (
  <>
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList 
       data={dataTest} 
       renderItem={({ item }) => renderData(item)} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </>
);
```

This code, It showing only the latest events are coming from the device. But I need a list that contains older and new upcoming events so that I can scroll the events data.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. Your `handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic` function is the issue here.

Currently, you are overwriting the previous state (thus forgetting al previous values) by setting the state to new `data.value`. You want to append incoming data to the existing results, instead of overwriting them.

So you could do something like this:

```js
const [dataTest, setDataTest] = useState([]);

const handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = (data) => {
  const prevData = [...dataTest];
  prevData.unshift(data.value); // unshift adds elements to the beginning of an array
  
  // instead of using the incoming data.value, we use the prevData array since we just added the new value to it.
  setDataTest(prevData);
};
```

Comment: Yes that will work too, but my problem was several.
1. I have too many events incoming at a time.
2. I did not used keyextractor.

Answer (score 0):

I asked [the same question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/qqox23/how_can_i_get_dynamically_updating_flatlist_in/). The solution provided by [__o_0](https://www.reddit.com/user/__o_0/) worked for me:

```
const handleUpdateValueForCharacteristic = useCallback(({value, peripheral, characteristic, service}) => {
const data = bytesToString(value);
setDataTest(prevData => {
return [...prevData, data]});},[])

const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
return ( 
<View><Text>{index}</Text></View>);};
    
const keyExtractor=(item,index,) => \${index}`;`

return (
    <>
    <SafeAreaView>
    <FlatList
    data={dataTest}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    />
    
    </SafeAreaView>
    </>
    );
    };
```